# Can I swap a buttons content databind to a different databind in code?

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-phone-8

I cannot find any examples to make me understand how and if I can change the databind in c# at the click of a button on, in my case a toggleswitch, Basically I have 32 buttons in my app and those 32 buttons act the same but need different text with-in them depending on some toggle switches they are currently databinded so the text can be saved and retrieved from local storage but what values it gets depends on the state of these toggle switches.

So I currently have :

```
<Button x:Name="_ovButton1" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource AppSettings}, Path=ovName1_1Value, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="2,0,250,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14" Height="72" FontWeight="Bold" MouseLeftButtonUp="_ovButton1_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseLeftButtonDown="_ovButton1_MouseLeftButtonDown" ClickMode="Hover" Hold="_ovButton1_Hold"/>
```

and I want when a user changes the state of a toggleswitch to change the

```
{StaticResource AppSettings}, Path=ovName1_1Value, Mode=TwoWay}
```

to for example:

```
{StaticResource AppSettings}, Path=ovName1_2Value, Mode=TwoWay}
```

but I cannot find any example that shows how to do that in c#
what code do I need to do that?

Comment: Do the buttons perform different actions based on the text? In other words, does button 1 always do 'X' when clicked? Or does it do 'Y' when the text is different?

Comment: No, let me clarify... this is the overall aim : I have 32 buttons that the action when pressing them is the same no matter what but I want the label to change dependent on the toggle switch that is selected (only one at a time) http://www.ctwo12.com/fsr/fsr5.png this is so I can allow the user save labels so they know what they are clicking... as you can see in the screenshot you have 6 toggles and a lot of buttons I want the same buttons to say for example on the first button button1 page1 then when the user hits the next toggle button1 page1 will become button1 page2... does that make sense?

Comment: So, 32 buttons, each performs a different action, but button 1 will ALWAYS do 'X' regardless of what text it shows? Why have the text change it is always does 'X'?

Comment: all 32 buttons need to send the same thing over sockets which controls 32 buttons on the pc software so they send for example buttonXX the software picks this up and sets the state of the button that the app user is pressing. There are 6 Tabbed pages of 32 buttons on the pc software the toggle switches just send the code to change the TABS, otherwise for example button 1 will change button1 on whatever page the pc software is on... so at the moment it all works fine... now what this controls is nightclub lighting

Comment: you need to label the buttons so you know what your doing i.e. 'strobe full on' or 'strobe half on' I got all the code working in the app to change the isolatedstorage of the buttons label so it saves when changed but I need to get those buttons to retrieve different labels dependent on what page you have selected with the toggle switches so people can label their buttons so they know what they are clicking does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the target of databinding in code like this:

```
MyData myDataObject = new MyData(DateTime.Now);      
Binding myBinding = new Binding("MyDataProperty");
myBinding.Source = myDataObject;
myText.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);
```

See more at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863.aspx

Comment: I had seen that but in my xaml code above (I know I'm feeling very stupid about this) but at what part in that code do you put the path part and were does the resource part go?

Answer (score 0):

-- Edit Note I don't have access to a WP8 Emulator to test this ---

In the view model it looks like this:

```
public List<string> Members 
{ 
    get { return _Members; }
    set { _Members = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } 
}
public MainVM()
{
    // Simulate Asychronous access, such as to a db.

    Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    Members = new List<string>() {"Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Omega"};
                });
}
```

The code behind on the main page sets the datacontext (shared with all the child controls) as such:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Set the windows data context so all controls can have it.
    DataContext = new MainVM();

}
```

The Mainpage Xaml to bind to members is like this

```
<Button Height="30"
        Width="80"
        Margin="10"
        DataContext="{Binding Members}"
        Content="{Binding Path=[0] }" />

<Button Height="30"
        Width="80"
        Margin="10"
        DataContext="{Binding Members}"
        Content="{Binding Path=[1] }"  />

<Button Height="30"
        Width="80"
        Margin="10"
        DataContext="{Binding Members}"
        Content="{Binding Path=[2] }"  />

<Button Height="30"
        Width="80"
        Margin="10"
        DataContext="{Binding Members}"
        Content="{Binding Path=[3] }"  />
```

The result is this visually:

[image]

I based this on my blog article Xaml: [ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017) for more info and a fuller example.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is going to be to use a collection of strings and bind to that collection. You can either change the collection when a toggle is switched, or keep 6 collections and bind to the collection that is for the toggle.

Xaml:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Buttons" ItemsSource="{Binding ButtonTextCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <toolkit:WrapPanel/>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Width="100" Height="70" Content="{Binding}" Click="OnButtonClick"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Your code-behind would have the event handler for your button click

```
private void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var text = ((Button) sender).Content.ToString();
    // Send the text
}
```

Your ViewModel would hold the `ButtonTextCollection` property and would change based on the toggle.

```
public ICollection<string> ButtonTextCollection
{
    get { return _buttonTextCollection; }
    set
    {
        _buttonTextCollection = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ButtonTextCollection");
    }
}
```

When you want to change the text, you would change the `ButtonTextCollection`

```
public void ChangeButtonText()
{
    ButtonTextCollection = new Collection<string> {"A", "B",...};
}
```