# 6 Pivot Items, 32 Buttons on each is there a good reason why the app slows noticeably?

Tags: c#, performance, button, windows-phone-8

I'm new to programming and c# but I have a fully functioning app and wanted to add some more features... so I re-designed a section just re-designed no code added yet... I just added a new page and added 6 pivotitems and on each pivot 32 buttons... that's 192 buttons in total there just simple buttons nothing spectacular but why is it when I run the app on my device and navigate to the page that the flash of colour that appears when you 'tap the button' starts to slowy get less and less responsive to a point I can quickly tap 5 buttons then a few seconds later all the animations will eventually finish.

I can't believe that many buttons could slow down the app to near death or should it? if not how can I fix it as I genuinely need 192 buttons! separated into 32 on 6 tabs/pages

Comment: I'd reconsider your requirements. There is no way you need 6 active pages and 192 buttons simultaneously, because the user can't see or access them simultaneously. Phones and tablets have limited resources, and you should only be keeping what you actually need *at this moment* in memory. Your design is seriously flawed.

Comment: they need to access 32 buttons and flick between them ideally as fast as possibly able to... my Colleague has an android app that has the same amount of buttons on one page! yet no degradation in performance...

Comment: a) Android <> Windows Phone 8. Comparing apples to oranges. b) Where can I find your colleague's app? I write (and use) Android software, and have never, ever seen an app that needed even 32 buttons simultaneously (even on a tablet), and definitely not one that needed 192 buttons on 6 tabs active **simultaneously**, so until you can provide proof I call bull. :-)

Comment: it's a 'remote' control for night club lighting software you have to respond to changes in music as fast as you possibly can so you need to access the right page at the right time quickly I had a plan to have 6 pages and 32 on each page so you can use your thumb to flick fast and down to correct buttons and pages this then sends signals over wifi through sockets which the software then updates the lights , for example hitting a strobe button would instantly fire the strobe you could either have it turn on and off like a latch or only stay on aslong as your holding the button...

Comment: the issue wasn't a problem in the first incarnation but the second it is as I need users to edit button labels and I don't know enough to change databinding on the fly so I can update button labels based on the state of 6 toggle switches the first incarnation doesn't allow them to change labels... His app is FreeStyler Remote Pro...

Comment: I'm going to guess your slowness is coming from the 192 sockets, if you have that many sockets open

Comment: No only one socket...  which is opened then the buttons just send messages through that socket...

Comment: I wrote a quick sample with six pivots and 32 buttons and say no slowdown on any of the pages

Comment: Can you show what it is you are doing? I was not able to reproduce the slowdown you are reporting

Comment: Shawn, I was just getting back to my project and noticed that in the xaml there was some added xaml that I certainly didn't add and thats 

     <Button.Background>
                                <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill"/>
                            </Button.Background>

removing that has stopped the slow down...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason Blend or VS 2012 express added

```
<Button.Background>
<ImageBrush Stretch="Fill"/>
</Button.Background>
```

in the button xaml once removing it the buttons are responsive again...

Answer (score 0):

The more xaml controls which have to be added require work and memory allocations on the phone's part in a shared tight environment.

I had a situation where 100 map pin points each had a pop up dialog which gave extra information. Each one of those dialogs slowed down the app noticeably just like you see. I had to give up on preloading all 100 dialogs even hidden.

What I read is that there seems to be some duplication pivot control on a tab with certain amount of buttons. Maybe redesign it where you only show one tab, one pivot control and 32 buttons, then depending on the tab selection, re-use the current items, but simply change the text to give the appearance of a change.

Regardless you need to scale back in some fashion.

-- Also --

Is data being loaded asynchronously? Or can the data be loaded before the page even comes up, but asynchronously? I had a Silverlight app which loaded a lot of the data onto the VM before certain pages came up. I used that paradigm on my last WP8 project with good results.

Between those two you will be able to scale back the load of this page to something more manageable.

--- Update ----

Gave an example on the OPs other question here:
[Can I swap a buttons content databind to a different databind in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202027/can-i-swap-a-buttons-content-databind-to-a-different-databind-in-code)

Comment: I was going to re-use all 32 buttons and update the data-binding for the buttons text dependent on a set of six switches but I cannot for the life of me find out how to achieve that... I'm absolutely on the lowest level of skills in c# (and any programming) which I hope to improve via Lynda Tutorials I got an answer on here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202027/can-i-swap-a-buttons-content-databind-to-a-different-databind-in-code but he never replied...

Comment: @AdamCollins see my answer on your other question.